# Push notification delegate method issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, push-notification

I am new to Objective C. In my app i need to implement push notification, i have created new app ID and i have created new provisioning profile also. i have finished all the steps mentioned in this [link](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services)

i have declared this delegate function in my appDelegate .m file.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken { 

        NSString *deviceTokens = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
        deviceTokens = [deviceTokens stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
        NSLog(@"registered device token %@", deviceTokens);
        self.deviceToken = deviceTokens; 
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err { 

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Error: %@", err];
    NSLog(@"String %@",str);    

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    for (id key in userInfo) {
        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);
    }    

}
```

But this delegate functions are not called. please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your AppDelegated didfinishLaunching with options write the following line

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, inside your app delegate

if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {

```
    //We check because ios7 cannot respond to this method and there will be a crash..
    UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;

    UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else {
    //This will work on ios7 devices and below
    UIRemoteNotificationType types = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:types];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

return YES;
```

Comment: I dont know how to get that first part of the code source to work, but make sure you are calling registerForRemoteNotifications method, on the application, otherwise it will not hit your push notification delegate methods because it hasnt attempted to registerForNotifications

Answer (score 0):

Use new delegate method

Swift: 
 func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)